# Which TV shows had the longest gaps between seasons? And why?

Tags: production

I'm trying to find a comprehensive list of shows with extremely long gaps between seasons, but most only include very recent shows with maybe a two-year gap at most. I'm wondering about much longer gaps than that, but I'm also curious as to *why* these shows came back after such huge gaps.

The best example I can think of is *The Jetsons*, which had a gap of twenty-two and a half years between its first season's ending (1963) and second season's beginning (1985). This was a case where the show initially didn't do great, but became extremely popular in daytime syndication in the 1980s, such that everyone was brought back to make a bunch more episodes, far more than had originally been produced.

Another show with a big gap is *Red Dwarf*, which had a gap of either ten or thirteen and a half years, depending on whether you count the *Back to Earth* episodes (2009) as a separate season. I don't know if there was a popular outcry for this show to come back or what though, as it's been less consistent in recent years than it was in initial run.

You might also count *Doctor Who*, with a gap of sixteen years from the end of the first series (1989), depending on whether the new series (2005) is considered a reboot or continuation, and whether the 1996 movie could be counted as breaking the gap into two pieces. This is another one that I'm not sure if there was any particular thing that caused the revival, and again, it's not a "pure" continuation because The Doctor is constantly played by a new actor, so it's almost like a bunch of different shows already.

Are there any other shows with gaps in the range of a decade or more? And was there any particular triggering event that brought them back?

Comment: With Red Dwarf (and I would count the Back To Earth 2009 special as it coming back), the BBC didn't want to produce any more episodes. Dave, which had been airing reruns of it, commissioned the special (alongside BBC Worldwide) as part of it airing original content. It wasn't so much an outcry for the show, more that it retained enough popularity for Dave to take a chance on it.

Comment: Twin Peaks season 2 ended on June 10 1991, and season 3 started May 21 2017, 25 years 11 months, and 1 day later.